# Detect everytime an image is zoomed in or zoomed out

Tags: android

I am using the photoview library of chris banes to handle all zoom events for my gallery.

I want to detect if the image has been zoomed in or has been zoomed out by the user without overriding all those double tap,and touch event methods.Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:-

I found a much better way to implement zoom detection which works for pinch zoom as well as double tap(any zooming event, without having to override each method).Found it nowhere on the web to detect a zoom event.If there's a much more efficient way, please let me know :)

(Also I am using chris banes photoview library to handle the zooming.)

So to detect a zooming event,get the rectangle of the current photoview and when a zoom event happens , OnMatrixChangeListener gets called and there you compare the rectangles to see .

(Now simply using this listener to handle a zooming event won't work, because the listener gets called, everytime you change your image,(in case you're using it in a gallery) ,it also gets called when the orientation of the screen is changed and also when simple no-zoom intending touches are made to the screen.)

Also, when the screen orientation changes,sometimes the photoview returns a 0 rectangle,so you have to check for that as well,here's my code:-

```
if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(Constants.ZOOM)) {
  photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(backgroundImage);

  mWindowRect = new RectF(photoViewAttacher.getDisplayRect());
  photoViewAttacher.setOnMatrixChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnMatrixChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {
      //need to differentiate between screen orientation
      if (mWindowRect.left == 0 && mWindowRect.top == 0 && mWindowRect.right == 0 && mWindowRect.bottom == 0) {
        mWindowRect = new RectF(rect);
      }

      if (Math.abs(mWindowRect.left - rect.left) < 2 && Math.abs(mWindowRect.top - rect.top) < 2 && Math.abs(mWindowRect.right - rect.right) < 2 && Math.abs(mWindowRect.bottom - rect.bottom) < 2) {
        viewPager.setLocked(false);
        thumbnailsContainer.startAnimation(appear);
        thumbnailsContainer.setClickable(true);
      } else {
        viewPager.setLocked(true);
        thumbnailsContainer.startAnimation(disappear);
        thumbnailsContainer.setClickable(false);
      }
      Log.i("ZOOM", "default rect: " + mWindowRect);
      Log.i("ZOOM", "zoom rect: " + rect);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a bunch of listeners, that can be notified, when a certain event on a `PhotoView` occurrs.
Refer to:
[IPhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/IPhotoView.java#L357)
Here I can see the listeners:

```
void setOnDoubleTapListener(GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener newOnDoubleTapListener);
void setOnScaleChangeListener(PhotoViewAttacher.OnScaleChangeListener onScaleChangeListener);
void setOnSingleFlingListener(PhotoViewAttacher.OnSingleFlingListener onSingleFlingListener);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: there are bunch of listeners and a bunch of ways to zoom in , and they get notified even when the user doesn't intend to zoom in

Comment: Looking at the [onScale implementation](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/PhotoViewAttacher.java#L499) the user is notified only when the listener is set. And doesn't modify the state of the view.

Comment: Even while scrolling through images, the method gets called and causes unintended behaviour.

Comment: Updating link for [onScale implementation](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/photoview/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/PhotoViewAttacher.java)